# Why is it slow to refresh ObservableCollection in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, observablecollection

I need to process 4000 message packets every second, from a total of 80 different IDs. I have a `DataGrid`. I have `ObservableCollection` binded to DataGrid. I tried 2 ways to refresh the UI without freezing. I was unsuccessful in both.

**1.Way**

If there is a message from a different ID, I add it to my collection. If it comes from the same ID, I delete the old one and get the new one.

```
          if (MessagePacket._jobs.Where(X => X.ID == dataPacket.ID).FirstOrDefault() == null)
            {
                MessagePacket._jobs.Add(dataPacket);
            }
            else
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < MessagePacket._jobs.Count; x++)
                {
                    if (MessagePacket._jobs[x].ID == dataPacket.ID)
                    {
                         MessagePacket._jobs.RemoveAt(x);
                         MessagePacket._jobs.Add(dataPacket);
                    }              
                }
            }
```

**2.Way**

I am modifying the data without deleting it and refreshing the collection.

***Note*** : I tried to refresh the collection every 50ms, not after every pack. It's still slow.

```
        if (MessagePacket._jobs.Where(X => X.ID == dataPacket.ID).FirstOrDefault() == null)
            {
                MessagePacket._jobs.Add(dataPacket);
            }
            else
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < MessagePacket._jobs.Count; x++)
                {
                    if (MessagePacket._jobs[x].ID == dataPacket.ID)
                    {
                        MessagePacket._jobs[x].DLC = dataPacket.DLC;
                        MessagePacket._jobs[x].RTR = dataPacket.RTR;
                        MessagePacket._jobs[x].IDE = dataPacket.IDE;
                        MessagePacket._jobs[x].Byte0 = dataPacket.Byte0;
                        MessagePacket._jobs[x].Byte1 = dataPacket.Byte1;
                        MessagePacket._jobs[x].Byte2 = dataPacket.Byte2;
                        MessagePacket._jobs[x].Byte3 = dataPacket.Byte3;
                        MessagePacket._jobs[x].Byte4 = dataPacket.Byte4;
                        MessagePacket._jobs[x].Byte5 = dataPacket.Byte5;
                        MessagePacket._jobs[x].Byte6 = dataPacket.Byte6;
                        MessagePacket._jobs[x].Byte7 = dataPacket.Byte7;
                        MessagePacket._jobs[x].Time = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
                        CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(MessagePacket._jobs).Refresh();

                    }
                }
            }
```

How can I speed up the up processes without freezing the ui. Or can you show an alternative way? Thank you from now.

Comment: Is this WPF, UWP or Windows.Forms as the answer could be different?

Comment: Is 50ms refresh rate even valuable for the end user?  You could throttle it to something more visually digestible.

Comment: Even if I do 500 ms, nothing changes, it still freezes. The project is a WPF project, I'm adding it to the tags.

Comment: 1. The Where will get slower and slower as the list grows. 2. If your item class supports INotifyPropertyChanged the second way would work without the Refresh call.

Comment: @Klaus Gütter The second does not support the way you mentioned. I will try it right away.

Comment: What do you mean with freezes? Complety unresponsive, or switching between responsive/unresponsive state? So realise that when you actually refresh the data the ui thread will be blocked for the duration of the process? so eg. if your process takes 10ms and you do it every 50ms, it will freeze 10ms every 50ms.

Comment: Note that you can simplify `MessagePacket._jobs.Where(X => X.ID == dataPacket.ID).FirstOrDefault() == null` to `MessagePacket._jobs.FirstOrDefault(X => X.ID == dataPacket.ID) == null` and then further to `!MessagePacket._jobs.Any(X => X.ID == dataPacket.ID)` or `MessagePacket._jobs.All(X => X.ID != dataPacket.ID)`. If you dev with VS, the 'Roslynator' plugin will give you hints about those simplifications.

Comment: Just try `MessagePacket._jobs[x] = dataPacket;` instead of copying all the data. You would not need to implement INotifypropertyChanged ro call Refresh().

Comment: By freezing, I mean instant freezes when I want to sort in the DataGrid or when I want to scroll up and down. The second way Klaus suggested produced a noticeable improvement in performance.

Comment: @Clemens suggestion also helped to improve readability. Thank you.

Comment: @Arkane I'll try the related simplification. Are there any other ways that can help with performance? Are there any additional details I should add to the post?

Comment: Could `MessagePacket._jobs` possibly contain multiple elements with ID equal to `dataPacket.ID`, or just a single one?

Comment: @Clemens, IDs in "MessagePacket._jobs" will be different from each other. In "dataPacket", it is not clear how many will come from the same ID per second.

Comment: "*IDs in "MessagePacket._jobs" will be different from each other.*" - so this means there is always exactly zero or one `x` where `MessagePacket._jobs[x].ID == dataPacket.ID` is true, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should be more efficient:

```
var p = MessagePacket._jobs.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == dataPacket.ID);

if (p == null)
{
    MessagePacket._jobs.Add(dataPacket);
}
else
{
    int i = MessagePacket._jobs.IndexOf(p);
    MessagePacket._jobs[i] = dataPacket;
}
```

You may also consider to turn `_jobs`  into an [ObservableDictionary](https://www.google.com/search?q=WPF+ObservableDictionary), so that you could simply write

```
MessagePacket._jobs[dataPacket.ID] = dataPacket;
```

Comment: First time I hear of `ObservableDictionary` is it available in `WPF` ?

Comment: It's not part of the framework, but you'll find implementations on the internet.

Comment: Thank you. I'll look into the link you sent and try it out.